# How to enable ethernet connection in Windows 11?

Tags: networking, ethernet, windows-11

In Windows 11, I primarily use ethernet connection. I accidentally right clicked and disabled it from network connections window. Now I can't see the option to enable it back on again. How can I enable it?? I tried network reset and it didn't work.

My laptop is a

System Model    DELL XPS 15 9570 64 bit
OS Name Microsoft Windows 11 Home
Version 10.0.22000 Build 22000

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Open an admin command prompt and type NETSH LAN /? to get a list of LAN commands.  Try both NETSH LAN show and NETSH LAN add.  Also try reinstalling your LAN Driver (Manufacturer will have the LAN driver.  Look in Device Manager and see if you can enable it in Device Manager.  Restart if you enable in Device Manager.  See even if restart enables it.

Comment: @omega - Update your question with a screenshot showing your hidden network devices in that case. The only Ethernet adapter you have is a USB device. Have you tried unplugging the device and plugging it in a different USB port?

Comment: Try the USB adapter.

Comment: Actually sorry, it is a usbc-hub

Comment: @omega - It doesn’t really matter it’s still a USB device. What is the model information for the device? Waiting on the update to your question to submit an answer

Comment: @Ramhound It is this https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B082WQVFB1/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Comment: That doesn’t tell me anything about the Realtek adapter.  I cannot verify I am suggesting the correct driver from the Windows Update Catalog.  Have you tried my suggestion of unplugging the USB device and plugging it in a different port?  You should update your question to indicate this adapter was a USB device.

Comment: It is a usb-c connection, I only have 1 port. My laptop is System Model DELL XPS 15 9570 64 bit OS Name Microsoft Windows 11 Home Version 10.0.22000 Build 22000

Comment: You have a USB port, so get (local store, Amazon) a USB LAN adapter and use that for Ethernet.

Comment: @omega - Please enable hidden devices within device manager and update your question. When you do this be sure the Ethernet connection is connected to your network

Comment: How do I show hidden devices?

Comment: I attached a another ethernet LAN adapter into my usbc and plugged in the ethernet cable to that 2nd adapter, and then my laptop recognizes ethernet. Something is wrong with the first usb hub. I think I disabled the ethernet on it itself or removed its driver.

Answer (score 1):

> In Windows 11, I primarily use ethernet connection. I accidentally
> right clicked and disabled it from network connections window. Now I
> can't see the option to enable it back on again.

**First thing** to try is to look in Device Manager and see if you can re-enable the LAN adapter.

However in a comment, you said the LAN adapter did not show up in Device Manager.

**Second thing** then is to look in the Manufacturer's support site for the LAN driver ( go to the web site for the PC manufacturer, enter your model number, and look for the LAN driver), download it and install the LAN driver. Be sure to restart.

**Third thing,** if reinstalling LAN driver does not work, is to consider there may be a hardware issue.

In this latter case, get a USB LAN Adapter with drivers for your machine and use that for Ethernet.

Comment: I attached a another ethernet LAN adapter into my usbc and plugged in the ethernet cable to that 2nd adapter, and then my laptop recognizes ethernet. Something is wrong with the first usb hub. I think I disabled the ethernet on it itself or removed its driver.